# How can I repeatedly read user input using Scanner java

Tags: java, input

I am trying to create a simple menu for my program that reads user input. Here's the code:

```
public void menu() {
        String command;

        System.out.println("To operate with words write: a");
        System.out.println("To operate with products write: b");

        System.out.print("\nGive the command: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        command = scanner.nextLine();

        if (command.equals("a")) {
            System.out.println("\nGood job! You have chosen the word program\n");
            System.out.println("You can only use the following commands: ");
            System.out.println("exit - to exit the program");
            System.out.println("add - to add a word into the map");
            System.out.println("lookup - to lookup a word into the map\n");
            System.out.print("Give a command: ");
            command = scanner.next();
            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                command = scanner.next();
                if(command.equals("add")){
                    this.addWord();
                }

                System.out.print("Give a command: ");
                command = scanner.next(); //Here I get the ERROR that throws Exception
            }
        }

        scanner.close();
    }

public static void main(String [] args)
{
     HashTableInterface table = new HashTable(); 
     Dictionary d = new Dictionary(table); 
     RepositoryInterface repo = new Repository(d); 
     ControllerInterface controller = new Controller(repo); 
     Console c = new Console(controller); 
     c.menu()
}
```

And here's a test with the exception I get:

```
To operate with words write: a
To operate with products write: b

Give the command: a

Good job! You have chosen the word program

You can only use the following commands: 
exit - to exit the program
add - to add a word into the map
lookup - to lookup a word into the map

Give a command: add
add
Give the word: mar
Give the word's plural: mere
The hash code for mar is: 3
Give a command: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at console.Console.menu(Console.java:56)
    at test.Prog.main(Prog.java:26)
```

I removed the second command = scanner.next() from the while loop but then it let's me read user input only once. How can solve this?

UPDATE: the AddWord method:

```
public void addWord() {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Give the word: ");
        String word = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Give the word's plural: ");
        String plural = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();

        controller.addTheWord(word, plural);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your main please.

Comment: @AliAlamiri This is my main: HashTableInterface table = new HashTable();
  Dictionary d = new Dictionary(table);
  RepositoryInterface repo = new Repository(d);
  ControllerInterface controller = new Controller(repo);
  Console c = new Console(controller);
  c.menu();

Comment: Can you post your addWord() method? Is it reading user input using nextLine()?

Comment: @CodingBird updated post with the method

Comment: are you getting user input from text file? One possible cause for NoSuchElementException to be thrown is because you try to read an input which has reach the end of the data

Comment: @CodingBird No, I'm using the keyboard input. I'm not reading from a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
InputStreamReader str= new InputStreamReader (System.in);
BufferedReader uinp= new BufferedReader (str);
String val;
val= uinp.readLine();
while (!".".equals(val)) {
//do your stuff
//..and after done, read the next line of the user input.
val= uinp.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Until and unless you give a "." , it keeps on asking for user input.

Comment: @MoldovanRazvan We cannot see your screen, actually. Please tell us, what the exception is. "I have an exception" is close to no useful information.

Comment: @Fildor Sorry! Here's the exception: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:325)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.

Comment: There was a typo in my code , i just edited,(typed unip instead of uinp), give a try now.

Comment: @BharathRallapalli The typo wasn't the problem. I am using Eclipse and it shows me if something's written wrong

Comment: I checked again , this code seems fine, i am able to supply input continuously.

Comment: @BharathRallapalli It works in a simple prgram. But if I move all the code in my menu method I still  get the exception @_@

Comment: @MoldovanRazvan the error may be you are closing InputStreamReader or BufferedReader.If yes then close them in a finally block..

Comment: @BharathRallapalli I finally found the error. I was closing the scanner in my addWord() method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `switch case` inside the `while` loop instead of `if`. The switch case should provide the functionality depending on the input provided by the user.

Comment: That seems irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @ViliamBúr Please elaborate.

Comment: The benefits of replacing an `if` block with `switch case` block is that if multiple branches test the same expression, the expression is evaluated only once. The expression in this specific case is `command.equals("add")`, and it is evaluated only once in the loop anyway. Calling the `equals` method on a String value repeatedly may be inefficient, but it wouldn't throw a NoSuchElementException, which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this:

```
public class test {

private static Scanner scanner;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    printmenu();      
    getinput();
}

private static void printmenu(){
    System.out.println("To operate with words write: a");
    System.out.println("To operate with products write: b");
}

private static void getinput(){
    System.out.print("\nGive the command: ");
    String command = "";
    while (!scanner.hasNext()) {

    }
    command = scanner.next();

    if (command.equals("a")) {
        System.out.println("\nGood job! You have chosen the word program\n");
        System.out.println("You can only use the following commands: ");
        System.out.println("exit - to exit the program");
        System.out.println("add - to add a word into the map");
        System.out.println("lookup - to lookup a word into the map\n");
        System.out.print("Give a command: ");

        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            command = scanner.next();
            if(command.contains("add")){

                addWord();
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(command);
            }
            getinput();
        }
    }
    else{
        scanner.close();
    }
}

public static void addWord() {

    System.out.print("Give the word: ");
    String word = scanner.next();
    System.out.print("Give the word's plural: ");
    String plural = scanner.next();
    //controller.addTheWord(word, plural);
}
```

}